# Increasing Gnome Shell FPS (dragging windows and terminals is not smooth)

Tags: linux, shell, gnome

Is there a way to increase the FPS of the animations in the Gnome shell? I'm using debian with the gnome shell, and after recently installing windows 10, I just now release how low the fps for gnome is. My computer is 12k, resources for display and computing is NOT the problem here. Is there a way to manually allow for the gnome environment to use more resources so I get better FPS?

(My little findings after digging around the internet is that the gnome environment only uses a single thread animations from cpu, so its not well optimized/cant at all increase the threads unless code is reworked, is this true?)

**Update:** Coming back to this issue, compiling the newest version of Mesa against the newest version of LLVM will result in the best (in terms of bleeding edge hardware) results. Also note below about keeping kernel and drivers up to date.

In my case, i needed to fetch Vega amd firmware for full functionality.

Additionally, this is a good place to start. https://wiki.debian.org/Mesa

Running "glxinfo | grep OpenGL" can show you if the display is being generated by the CPU or GPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, my suggestion is updating your `graphic driver` or `kernel` on linux. You can find the latest version drivers on the website of your graphical card vendor :)

Comment: I'm using Debian stretch running kernel 4.15 (complied from source), with a vega 64. I fetched the latest firmware files from AMD and fetched the latest AMDGPU from backports.

Comment: Currently, I think that may be the maximum performance of this version driver. Or ~ you can give some feedback to offcial supporter or community to ask some help. Or you can search some **unofficial drivers** from `github` (or other sites like that) and try your luck , maybe some geeks already patched for that  :p

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the bottle neck in Gnome Shell is the CPU, not the GPU. If you can force your CPU to run at a higher frequency that might make a difference.